# When did sqlalchemy execute the query?

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy

As I've just start learning to use sqlalchemy recently, the result of the following code make me confused about when sqlalchemy execute the query:

```
query = db.session.query(MyTable)
query = query.filter(...)    
query = query.limit(...)   
query = query.offset(...)    
records = query     #records=query.all()
for r in records:
    #do something
```

note the line

```
records = query #records=query.all()
```

Seems that it brings the same correct result(stored in variable "records") when using *"query"* and *"query.all()"*, I wonder when was the query executed?

If it is executed during the first line *"db.session.query(MyTable)"*, the  result set may be large at this point; if during the fifth line *"records = query"*, how could that happen as there's no function call at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, the query gets executed upon `for r in records`. Accessing the query object via iterator triggers the execution. (Normally, only then will it be compiled into a `SELECT` statement)

Up until this time, the query will be built (via `filter`, `limit` etc).

Please read also the [ORM Tutorial on querying](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/tutorial.html#querying)

Comment: I'm clear now, this trigger point is interesting, thanks so much!